# Inception V3 Running Stats?

Tags: tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, inception

Has anyone created statistics on how fast and accurate Inception V3 can classify an image based on criteria such as: different models of GPUs/CPUs, input image size, input image ratio, file format, how it runs on iOS and Android, etc?

Example chart I'd hope to see:

```
GPU | CPU | Ratio |   Size   |  Speed  | Accuracy    
 x           1:1     100x100    1000ms     93%
       x     3:4     3k x 4k   40000ms     95%
```

X as in type of GPU/ CPU